# Easy way to convert an Array to a Collection in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, collections

Is there an easy way to populate a Collection with all Values from an Array in VBA?
e.g. something like

```
Dim c As New Collection
Dim a(10) As Variant
...
c.AddAll a
```

A simple solution would be of cause to iterate over the array, but I would expect that a modern language offers such methods out of the box ...

```
Dim c As New Collection
Dim a(10) as Variant
...
For Each item in a
  c.Add item
Next item
```

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"modern language" is where your problem lies - VBA/VB6 aren't really modern - neither have been advanced much for some years.

If you need to do it a lot, write a function to do the looping:

```
Sub AddAll(ByVal c as Collection, a as Variant)
    For Each item in a
      c.Add item
    Next item
End Sub
```

or if you want a new collection each time:

```
Function ToCollection(a as Variant) As Collection
    Dim c As New Collection
    For Each item in a
      c.Add item
    Next item
    Set ToCollection = c
End Function
```

and then use it:

```
Dim c As New Collection
Dim a(10) as Variant
...
AddAll c,a
```

or

```
Dim a(10) as Variant
Dim c as Collection
...
Set c = ToCollection(a)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your quick help! There might be a reason why I usually don't prefer VBA ;-)